# With CSS, how can I force text to break at a certain point only if it wouldn't break at all otherwise?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I have some text which would ideally display as two lines. It's trivial to get this behavior with a `<br>` element:

```css
div {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
    This is some text<br>
    Should be >1 line
</div>
```

However, at small screen widths, this results in some awkward looking broken lines:

[image: screenshot of text wrapping onto 4 lines (this is some / text / should be >1 / line)]

I'd much rather this wrap in the most compact way possible (as it would without the `<br>` element) rather than it doing this. I could set the container to have a max width of the length of the longest line of text:

```css
div {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    This is some text
    Should be >1 line
</div>
```

but that makes my CSS depend on what font/size/text is being used which is not ideal (and I could calculate that number with client side JS but I feel like there should be a less janky way to do this).

How can I obtain the desired behavior with just CSS and no magic numbers?

Comment: Why not use `text-align: justify` to have to spread over as many lines as it needs? What is the actual _goal_ you're aiming for? I.e. what is the real text you're dealing with, and how should the user experience that text? (plus, have you considered media queries to style things differently at different widths?)

Comment: The actual site is at https://home.obl.ong (the "Free, quality domains for all, / backed by a nonprofit"). My goal is that the text breaks into two lines with the specified spot as the ideal spot to break, since then it naturally flows into two "points" about the product. However, if it needs to wrap any more (at low screen widths) it just wraps normally, ignoring that preference, so it doesn't look weird. I do have some media queries already, but I'd like to be able to have the text wrap instead of just getting progressively smaller (and not have to update breakpoints when I edit the text).

Comment: @Merlin04 so you want to break line only specific point or else not then please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aorfwhc0/

Comment: That's not quite the behavior I'm looking for, that still creates the awkward looking lines (like in my screenshot in the question) - it shouldn't have each line wrap independently, it should just break at the specified point if it wouldn't break otherwise (so it isn't a really long single line, and I can choose where it breaks for the case most people will see)

Comment: are spans with a `white-space: no-wrap` an option? Then the browser _has_ to break between spans (but then you can get overflow issues if you don't write proper media queries, because you want to remove that no-wrap on small widths)

Answer (score 2):

You can write Media Query or you can use Bootstrap.

By Media Query :

```
 <div>
        This is some text<br>
        Should be >1 line
    </div>
```

And

```
@media (max-width:575px) { br { display: none; }
```

By Bootstrap :

```
<div>
    This is some text<br class="d-none d-sm-block">
    Should be >1 line
</div>
```